# What's this weird drawArc() / arcTo() bug (graphics glitch) in Android?

Tags: android

I ran my code on my Nexus 7 whilst it still had Android 4.3 installed. I then upgraded to Android 4.4 and ran my code again. Below are my findings on a weird Canvas.drawArc() / Path.arcTo() bug (graphics glitch) ...

**First Method**

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas)
{
    super.onDraw(canvas);

    //draw Background
    canvas.drawRect(mOuterArcRectangle, mBackgroundPaint);

    //draw arc
    Path path = new Path();
    path.arcTo(mInnerArcRectangle, mAngleStart, mSweep);
    canvas.drawPath(path, mPaint);
}
```

**State**

```
mOuterArcRectangle = RectF(0.0, 0.0, 1080.0, 1080.0)
mInnerArcRectangle = RectF(150.0, 150.0, 930.0, 930.0)
mAngleStart = 120
mSweep = 135
```

**causes this result...**
[image]

**2nd method**

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas)
{
    super.onDraw(canvas);

    //draw Background
    canvas.drawRect(mOuterArcRectangle, mBackgroundPaint);

    //draw arc
    canvas.drawArc(mInnerArcRectangle, mAngleStart, mSweep, false, mPaint);
}
```

**State**

```
mOuterArcRectangle = RectF(0.0, 0.0, 1080.0, 1080.0)
mInnerArcRectangle = RectF(150.0, 150.0, 930.0, 930.0)
mAngleStart = 120
mSweep = 135
```

**causes this result...**
[image]

**On Android 4.4**
Either method results in (what I would consider successful)

[image]

**Solution ?**
Is there a workaround for this problem? Is it a known problem ?

Comment: I've observed that disabling hardware acceleration alters the graphics glitch (I was hoping it would fix it)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've fixed it simply by adding `0.5f` to the sweep angle before drawing the arc.