# Why does Canvas::drawArc method draw incorrect angles?

Tags: android, canvas, draw

I'm trying to draw a 180° arc within an android view.
In the `onDraw` method I'm using `Canvas::drawArc` like this:

```
canvas.drawArc(arcRect, 180.0f, 180.0f, false, arcBackgroundPaint);
```

The Paint that is being used has a `strokeCap` of type `BUTT`. As you can see in the image below, the ends of the arc do not look quite right. The ends are angled up slightly from the inner diameter to the outer diameter.

[image: 180 degree arc]

Does anyone know why this is happening? Is there a way to fix it other than changing the values passed to drawArc so that it actually draws more than 180 degrees? That seems like a nasty hack that I'd rather avoid.

UPDATE:
As requested, I added code to draw a straight line at the bottom of the arc. I draw the line before I draw the arc so the line is behind. I also made the arc black to get better contrast with the line. Here is the outcome:
[image]
Yuck.

Here's one with anti-aliasing turned off for the line and arc...
[image]

Comment: I've tested with same  setting. but this does not happen. Please add a strait line at the bottom of the arc to check drawArc() is the cause or not.

Comment: Same here. I can't reproduce the problem.

Comment: @Toris  Please see my update above. I've tried on several OS versions and screen sizes. It happens everywhere but the difference is definitely more noticeable on smaller screens. The images were captured on a device with HDPI 480x800.

Comment: @KalaBalik If you're not able to reproduce this would you mind posting an answer with the code you used in `onDraw` including your paint definition? I'd like to compare it with mind.

Comment: @PICyourBrain I've posted current code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

drawArc incorrect angles problem will occur **if hardware acceleration is on**.

Reproduced with real phone (Nexus 5, Android 6.0.1).

How to test:
Add `android:hardwareAccelerated="false"` to application tag in AndroidManifest.xml.

NB:
First supported API level of drawArc() is not found in the document, but scaling function of it is from API17.

Hardware Acceleration > Canvas Scaling
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/hardware-accel.html

> First supported API level
>   Simple Shapes: 17
>   Note: 'Simple' shapes are drawRect(), drawCircle(), drawOval(), drawRoundRect(), and drawArc() (with useCenter=false) ...

Updated:
As PICyourBrain wrote in another answer, `drawArc()` is a part of reasons this problem occurs.

With `drawPath()`, this problem does not occur.

For information:
Not a same shape but `drawArc()` with useCenter=true also seems safe to use, as hardware acceleration is not used for it. (Ends of the arc and center of it are connected with line, and the line seems straight.)

Canvas Scaling (same link above)

> First supported API level
>   Complex Shapes: x

---

Other Q&As related to `drawArc()`

[Canvas.drawArc() artefacts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25150598/canvas-drawarc-artefacts)

[What's this weird drawArc() / arcTo() bug (graphics glitch) in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20795658/whats-this-weird-drawarc-arcto-bug-graphics-glitch-in-android)

---

[Old]
I'll leave these for your information.

Here are some test results I've tried.

Updated 1-1:

With emulator Nexus5 API10, with `arcRect = new RectF(100, 100, 1500, 1400);`.
[image]
With emulator Nexus5 API16, this does not happen.
(The difference is existence of (host side) hardware acceleration.)

I thought this seems to be an anti-alias related problem, but this happens no matter `arcBackgroundPaint.setAntiAlias(true)` or `setDither(true)` are set or not.

NB: This is caused by typo, sorry. Aspect ratio of arcRect should be 1:1 for this test.
With `arcRect = new RectF(100, 100, 1400, 1400);` and `arcPenWidth = 200f;`
[image]

With `arcRect = new RectF(100, 100, 1500, 1300);`
[image]

1-2: for comparison
With emulator NexusOne (480x800, HDPI) API10, with `arcRect = new RectF(100, 100, 500, 500);`
[image]

Updated 2: Line extended.
I first thought drawing out of view may cause this, but this is also a emulator bug. (Not a drawArc() specific behavior.)
With emulator API10 in landscape(horizontal) orientation, this occurs.
Calculation of line position seems broken.
Please see the right end of the straight line.

```
final float lineStartX = arcRect.left - 250f;
final float lineEndX = arcRect.right + 250f;
```

emulator Nexus5 API10
[image]

horizontal (API10)
[image]

vertical (API10)
[image]

2-2: Just for a information
View odd behavior sample of view position (or drawing position) out of range.

[image]
[image]

Updated 3: Emulator bug

Please see the bottom of the image.
Blue line is a background image of desktop.
emulator Nexus5 API10

[image]

Update 4: The result seems to depend on style.
With title bar
[image]

Without title bar
[image]

Update 5: The result seems to depend on line width.

With arcPenWidth = 430f (API10, horizontal)
Slight notch on the right side is seen.
[image]

With 440f
[image]

With 450f
[image]

---

Here's my (first) test code.

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.RectF;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.View;

final class TestView extends View
{
    RectF arcRect;
    Paint arcBackgroundPaint;
    Paint linePaint;

    public TestView(final Context context, final AttributeSet attrs)
    {
        super(context, attrs);
        //arcRect = new RectF(100, 100, 500, 500);
        arcRect = new RectF(100, 100, 1500, 1500); // fixed (old: 1500, 1400)
        arcBackgroundPaint = new Paint();
        arcBackgroundPaint.setColor(0xFFFFFFFF);
        arcBackgroundPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        arcBackgroundPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.BUTT);
        arcBackgroundPaint.setStrokeWidth(200f);
        linePaint = new Paint();
        linePaint.setColor(0xFF00FF00);
        linePaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        linePaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.BUTT);
        linePaint.setStrokeWidth(2f);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(final Canvas canvas)
    {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        canvas.drawArc(arcRect, 180.0f, 180.0f, false, arcBackgroundPaint);
        final float lineStartX = arcRect.left - 50f;
        final float lineEndX = arcRect.right + 50f;
        final float lineY = arcRect.centerY();
        canvas.drawLine(lineStartX, lineY, lineEndX, lineY, linePaint);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for investigating. Anti-aliasing does make it worse but it does still happen even with anti-aliasing off. I took the example code you posted, changed the colors to BLACK and WHITE and moved the drawLine above the drawArc, and also extended the lines out past the ends of the arc and it becomes much more obvious.

Comment: @PICyourBrain I experienced some odd view behavior many months ago, and it was caused by drawing out of view or like that, as far as I remember.

Comment: I ran the example code on a real phone (Nexus 6) and it looks exactly like the images I posted in my original question up above. So I think I've ruled out an emulator bug. The only image I've seen that looks close to correct is your update 1-2 version. But I wonder if it's just not noticeable because the line is on top of the arc. I bet if you make the line white and the arc dark and put the line behind we would see the same effect that I observed. I'm still convinced it's just a bug in `drawArc`.

Comment: Your suggestion that it's caused by drawing outside of the view's bounds is interesting. Although in my case, I think my arc is entirely within the bounds of the view. The arcRect extends below the bottom of the view but the arc is only drawn in the top half.

Comment: @PICyourBrain I ran my code on emu and real phone (Nexus 5) with the line before the arc. and the arc seems to cross the line a dot, but not so obvious. Also tried `canvas.drawArc(arcRect, 180.0f, 180.01f, false, arcBackgroundPaint);` and no crossing the line. May be a float calculation trick.

Comment: @PICyourBrain Sorry. I found a typo in my code. Please change `arcRect = new RectF(100, 100, 1500, 1400);` to `(..., 1500, 1500)`. If I set it `(..., 1500, 1300)`, the arc shape looks  like a question one, and the line also distorted, with API10, so aspect ratio of arcRect is one of a factor, I think.

Comment: Wow! Thanks for digging into this. It's been really helpful.

Answer (score 3):

For anyone else who comes across this I did find a workaround. Instead of using `Canvas::drawArc`, create a Path, add an arc to it and then draw the path on the canvas. Like this:

```
Path arcPath = new Path();
Rect arcRect = ... // Some rect that will contain the arc
path.addArc(arcRect, 180, 180); 
canvas.drawPath(arcPath, backgroundArcPaint);
```

Then the rendering problem highlighted no longer occurs.

Since my question was not "how do I fix the problem" but rather "why is this a problem" I am not marking this as the correct answer.

Comment: Great! I think this also be an answer, as this shows `drawArc()` is a part of reason this problem occurs. And.. small typo. path in the 2nd line is arcPath. (and 3rd line arcPaint is arcBackgroundPaint)